# when git status is executed nuxt is hot-reloading the project

Tags: git, webpack, nuxt.js, hot-reload

Is there a way to ignore .git on hot-reload?

When I run `git status`, nuxt says `↻ Updated .git/index.lock` and reload the project build.

I'm expecting that git commands don't call hot-reload.

Comment: Ideally, this shouldn't be reading the `.git` directory at all. From the Git side of things you have two options here: separate the Git directory from the deployment (that's usually the best option by far: don't use Git to deploy software, it's a terrible deployment system; at least consider putting the `.git` directory elsewhere). Or, use `git status --no-optional-locks` so that `git status` won't update the index and hence won't need to create the `index.lock` file.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, I've tried adding this to `nuxt.config`

```
  watchers: {
    webpack: {
      ignored: ['.git/**/*'],
    },
    chokidar: {
      ignored: ['.git/**/*'],
    },
  }
```

which should make the watcher ignore .git directory, but it does not make any difference. Maybe it works for you.